# Securely launch local application from IE or alternative ways?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, windows-10, wsh, windows-scripting

I am facilitating an information system project in intranet environment( with internet access for many users), in which user can print barcode labels from a web interface.

The current method our vendor employed is to create a windows script `fso` object to launch a local bar code designing application from IE passing a temporary license key, without it the application will quit with error.
For this to work, it requires enabling insecured ActiveX content in IE setting.

Also our security policy blocks any writing by regular users to `C:\Program Files` location, and running of any executable outside of `Program Files` folder. This barcode software needs a write lock to a lic file in its program folder or it crashes.

Currently, I have to add this intranet address to `trusted sites` list and `enable insecure activex content` for `trusted zone`. Added `Full` control ACL permission of the lic file to current domain user, so that the program can lock its lic file.

I thought `wsh` is an antique from XP times should be long dead. With these same permission. XSS injected payload could do a lot more harm on the system. I still not feel comfortable with current solution.

Provided I am stuck with this label printing solution. is there any more secured way to do this programmatically from a browser (not even necessarily IE.).

More importantly, if we move on to Window 10, will the default browser still support creating this `wsh` related objects?

Comment: Why not to use [a pure client side JS solution](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=jquery+barcode)?

Comment: By barcode I really mean product labels. The template needs to be editable to our product department guys (has to assume 0 knowledge in coding, they are used to Zebra environment, this software is similar even easier to use. I don't have much to complain on the software usability.).